# Using Spring-Data/MongoDB findBy/IsFalse with reserved keyword

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have a structure that looks kind of like this:

```
{
 'foo': 'bar',
 'isBaz': false
}
```

and the following Repository code

```
repository.findByIsBazIsFalse();
```

I figured that would only return records where isBaz is false, but it's also returning records where isBaz is set to true.  My initial guess is that the field starts with the word 'is' which is a reserved keyword in the spring/mongo query.

FWIW I also tried via annotation but no luck

```
@Query("{isBaz:false}")
```

Does anyone know how to make it work without renaming the variable to 'baz'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure this field is defined as `boolean` and it should work!

```
private boolean isBaz;
```

---

```
repository.findByIsBazIsFalse();
[main] o.m.d.p.c :Sending command '{"find": "collection", "filter": {"isBaz": false}, ...}'
```

Comment: Ended up being a typo on my end but thanks for responding